# how to change Photorec's output filefolder

Tags: software-installation, data-recovery

due to a wrong hd firmat instead off hdd need badly to use photorec.

How do i change Photorec's output filefolder to the public file folder?

Answer (score 0):

Use  `/d` option. Reference: `man photorec`

> ```
> photorec [/log] [/debug] [/d recup_dir] [device|image.dd|image.e01]
> ```